# how to implement realtime map for a lot of users with realtime movement updates in iOS?

Tags: ios, maps, pubnub

I have been looking at pubnub but it requires licence payment etc. I was wondering if there is way to implement maps in swift 3 iOS where location of users are updated by respective app users realtime,in a way realtime movement can be shown to a user about friends near his area say 1km radius. I heard socket.io is the best approach. I am unable to find any useful content to work upon in iOS using native Xcode.

Comment: This question is too broad. You need to ask a more focused question, and be prepared to do more investigative work up front yourself.

Comment: a more focused question would be how to implement realtime mapping without using long polling of webservice, I need a direction in the right way. thats all I need.

Comment: To get updates from a server to a client without polling, you could look into Apple Push Notifications:  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1

Comment: that is useful in the case of limited users right? What if the case scenario is for an area of users.

Comment: Please explain how you intend this to work. It sounds like you have thought up something unfeasible.

Answer (score 0):

PubNub does support the real-time mapping.  There is an open source framework called EON that you can try out for yourself:

https://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/

https://github.com/pubnub/eon-map

PubNub is free to use up to a million messages per month and one hundred daily devices. Then it's tiered up from there.  PubNub is a globally distributed network which means that when your application gains more traction, PubNub will scale with you.